# Is there a platform agnostic way to reference a file on a windows share in Java

Tags: java, windows, macos, filenames

(After some searching, I'm beginning to think this is not possible, but that seems "crazy")

If I have a file located on a remote server with a windows share (we'll assume the UNC is "\svr\shr\dir1\dir2\file.txt"), is there not some way to specify that file location to a java program that may run on Windows or Mac (or potentially even Linux)?

I thought *maybe* a URI like "file://svr/shr/dir1/dir2/file.txt" might do the trick, but that isn't working, nor is just using the string of the UNC (with slashes reversed (i.e. "//svr/shr/dir1/dir2/file.txt"))